# How to determine that a screensaver is running?

Tags: windows, winapi, screensaver

One solution that one could suggest is to periodically look for a special 'Screen-saver' desktop, and if it's present then count it as a running screensaver.

But apparently this is not the case for all screensavers as with some the mentioned desktop is always present.

Are there more reliable solutions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key is to identify the screensaver by its window class ("WindowsScreenSaverClass"). I found this page 
[How do I start, detect and stop screen savers?](http://bobmoore.mvps.org/Win32/w32tip22.htm) that has some code examples and explanations.

Answer (score 10):

See the WINAPI function SystemParametersInfo() with the SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING parameter. It's the only documented way to detect whether the screen saver is currently running. (You can also find out if a screen saver is even enabled, get and set the timeout value, and start the screen saver using this function.)

Answer (score 1):

[HOW TO: Determine If Screen Saver Is Running by Using Visual Basic 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315725)

I know this is for VB6, but it's bound to be a good place to start.

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36945940/410624) is my implementation of screen saver event detection.

Notes:

- `SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING` detects Windows Event id 4802 and 4803 which weren't accurate in my case, see [my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941113/windows-event-id-4802-and-4803-triggered-at-the-same-time-invoke-dismissal-of) hence user idle time calculation is added
- `GetLastInputInfo` apparently doesn't work if process is a service.

Answer (score -2):

search processes for a process with .scr in its .MainModule.FileName