# Change desktop background of MAC sytem using Java native access

Tags: java, jna

I have got a code snippet to change system desktop using [JNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750372/can-i-change-my-windows-desktop-wallpaper-programmatically-in-java-groovy), it is worked fine for me.

What change i need to make this code for working on Mac Os.

Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shihab.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to Map the NSWorkspace class to JNA. Define an interface that extends Library class in JNA. Then map the `setDesktopImageURL:forScreen:options:error:` method ot JNA.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Be sure to look at rococoa.java.net, which provides a number of useful adaptations for working with OSX libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it without JNA.

```
public void setWallpaper(File file)
throws Exception {
    String as[] = {
            "osascript", 
            "-e", "tell application \"Finder\"", 
            "-e", "set desktop picture to POSIX file \"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"",
            "-e", "end tell"
    };
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process;
    process = runtime.exec(as);
}
```

Credits

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5007344/1401250

https://sourceforge.net/p/jawc-wallpaperc/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Jawc/src/it/jwallpaper/platform/impl/MacPlatform.java#l38