# Changing wallpaper and stretch it on Windows platform using Java(with JNA)

Tags: java, jna

I am looking for a way to change the wallpaper on Windows 7 using the "Stretched" method in Java.
I found this:
[Can I change my Windows desktop wallpaper programmatically in Java/Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750372/can-i-change-my-windows-desktop-wallpaper-programmatically-in-java-groovy)
This approach work but uses the "Centered" method.
I also tried to import the Jawc project into eclipse, but I get runtime errors I can't resolve(Stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/Dqmsgqtv).

Comment: If you want help on the errors perhaps posting a stacktrace would help.

Comment: Have you looked at the References in the link you provided. They show the registry keys for setting tiling etc the background. I'd try fiddling with those.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the second phase? Sorry for being noob. It dont know JNA, I does not even look like java syntax.

Comment: Here is the stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/Dqmsgqtv

Comment: It looks like you have not correctly assigned JNA native libraries path in Java properties `jna.library.path` and `java.library.path`. That is why it triggers `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no tray in java.library.path` since the file path relative to where the java program runs named `./tray` does not exist.

Comment: It may be looking for tray.dll, locate it and then set -Djava.library.path equal to the dir where dll resides.