# java code for changing wallpaper in windows 7

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, wallpaper

Can I change wallpaper of windows 7 using Java code?

Here's my code:

```
public class Changer {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static native int SystemParametersInfo(int uiAction,int uiParam,String pvParam,int fWinIni);

    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("user32");
    }

    public int Change(String path)
    {
       return SystemParametersInfo(20, 0, path, 0);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String wallpaper_file = "D:\\Photos\\walli\\dream girls\\jes54d.jpeg";
        Changer mychanger = new Changer();
        mychanger.Change(wallpaper_file);
    }
}
```

This code in Eclipse IDE failed. I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.changer.Changer.SystemParametersInfo(IILjava/lang/String;I)I
    at com.changer.Changer.SystemParametersInfo(Native Method)
    at com.changer.Changer.Change(Changer.java:18)
    at com.changer.Changer.main(Changer.java:25)
```

I am new to Java and couldn't figure out what would be the possible solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Function call `SystemParametersInfo(20, 0, path, 0)` is wrong. It expects `SystemParametersInfo(UINT_PTR uiAction, UINT_PTR uiParam, String pvParam, UINT_PTR fWinIni)`.

Refer [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750372/can-i-change-my-windows-desktop-wallpaper-programmatically-in-java-groovy) answer here.

You can get JNA from [here](https://github.com/twall/jna). And refer javadocs [here](http://twall.github.io/jna/3.5.2/javadoc/).