# How can we temporarily disable the desktop wallpaper to black screen using Java

Tags: java

We are able to disable the wallpaper to black, but it goes permanent black.

Can there be a better option to temporarily disable the desktop wall paper tillour application is running on the computer.

Comment: _disable the desktop wall paper tillour application is running_ why do you want to do so? users will get angry if you try to override their personal preferences.

Comment: Only till our remote toll developed  in java is running it should remain disable and after the remote toll stops, it should revert the old wallpaper, like team viewer does. But ours is in java. this is the only reason.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [JAWC](http://jawc-wallpaperc.sourceforge.net/) framework

> It is a Plugin-Based Wallpaper Changer and can change your desktop
>   background picture from a lot of different sources like your PC's
>   folders, or Flickr, or VladStudio, just depending on which plugins you
>   enable

Comment: I tried this, it  changes it permanently, but do not know how to revert it back. And also we have a stand alone application running, its not a web based application.its just like team viewer but in java.

Comment: @ShekharRana, you changed it for the first time, just change it again :)

Comment: our remote tool is developed in java and it should disable thedestop wallpaper and after the remote tool stops, it should revert the old wallpaper, like team viewer does.

Comment: You mean you can't obtain the original wallpaper information to set it again ?

Comment: Try this approache
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750372/can-i-change-my-windows-desktop-wallpaper-programmatically-in-java-groovy

Comment: @ShekharRana, How did it go ?