# How to change the desktop wallpaper in java without saving the wallpaper to disk

Tags: java

I know, a lot of people already asked how to change the desktop wallpaper, and I found a particular well-working example in this post: [Can I change my Windows desktop wallpaper programmatically in Java/Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750372/can-i-change-my-windows-desktop-wallpaper-programmatically-in-java-groovy)

HOWEVER, I wish to change my wallpaper every second: simply load in a template, draw a clock and other data in it, save it to disk, point windows to the new file so it can use it as a wallpaper. This seems very "hacky" as a wallpaper is written multiple times per second to disk.
Is there a way where I can point the OS to the BufferedImage instead of saving it to disk?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot do this, and even if there was a function to do it, it would not really be as "unhacky" as you appear to think it would be, because that function would *have to work* by saving your image to a file.  You see, windows must be able to find the desktop wallpaper after the next reboot, so it must be kept in a file somewhere.  So, what if you go through the hassle of saving the image to the file, versus Windows going through the same hassle? Both approaches are equivalently hacky.