# creating a fullscreen desktop environment?

Tags: java, qt, desktop, fullscreen

how to create a fullscreen application, with no window frame, to simulate a 'virtual desktop'?
I would like to know if it's possible using java and Qt C++? and what are the syntaxe for doing such thing in both languages?

Comment: you can do it using java. 

Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890379/java-setfullscreenwindow-hides-log-in-dialog-in-mac/6890658#6890658

Comment: You can use `QDesktopWidget` in Qt to handle full screen, multiple monitor, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show a Qt widget fullscreen:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QWidget widget;

  //widget.show();  
  widget.showFullScreen();

  app.exec();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: in java this solution works: GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(this);