# Check if screensaver is active

Tags: java, windows, screensaver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine if a screensaver is running in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057492/how-to-determine-if-a-screensaver-is-running-in-java)

is there any way you can find out if the screensaver is active with java? I've searched the web but the only things I found was very complicated native code... My program is made for windows only.

Comment: I would recommend switching to C# asap if you are targetting Windows only

Comment: @bobobobo, I take it you've never worked on a project that already has tens or hundreds of thousands of lines of code.

Comment: Judging by the nature of the question it sounds as if he is in the beginning stages

Answer (score 2):

Java cannot handle system tasks directly.
You should use JNI (Java Native Interface) or JNA (Java Native Access) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this code, but they claim to answer your question with JNA as Ammar suggested: [Screen Saver State.](http://osdir.com/ml/java.jna.user/2007-11/msg00009.html)