# How to check screen status from Java JFrame

Tags: java, linux, swing, jframe

I have a Java JFrame application running on Linux where I need to check the status of the screen (i.e. whether or not the screen saver has been activated). Is there anyway to use a Java built-in function like System or Toolkit to check the screen properties and if the screensaver is activated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine if a screensaver is running in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057492/how-to-determine-if-a-screensaver-is-running-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Java cannot handle system tasks directly. You should use JNI (Java Native Interface) or JNA (Java Native Access) to do it. Try using the [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) library to invoke the [SystemParametersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947%28VS.85%29.aspx) system call like this:

The following example uses code from the [win32 examples](https://github.com/twall/jna/source/browse/jna/trunk/jnalib/src/com/sun/jna/examples/win32/) provided by JNA:

```
public class JNATest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        W32API.UINT_PTR uiAction = new W32API.UINT_PTR(User32.SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING);
        W32API.UINT_PTR uiParam = new W32API.UINT_PTR(0);
        W32API.UINT_PTR fWinIni = new W32API.UINT_PTR(0);
        PointerByReference pointer = new PointerByReference();

        User32.INSTANCE.SystemParametersInfo(uiAction, uiParam, pointer, fWinIni);

        //Is false if 0, is true if 1.
        boolean running = pointer.getPointer().getByte(0) == 1;

        System.out.println("Screen saver running: "+running);
    }
}


public interface User32 extends W32API {

    User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class, DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    long SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING = 0x0072;

    boolean SystemParametersInfo(
        UINT_PTR uiAction,
        UINT_PTR uiParam,
        PointerByReference pvParam,
        UINT_PTR fWinIni
      );


}
```